# Facebook share button error

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Please I recently added a share button on my site. It works well when I am logged onto facebook and share. The other issue is that each time someone else tries to share, it shows an error message that the "APP IS STILL IN DEVELOPMENT MODE" etc.
How can I fix these error please.
My code below;

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'MY APP ID HERE',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.5'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#share_button').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
FB.ui(
{
method: 'feed',
name: 'GIST ON CELEBRITIES.',
link: ' http://mysitehere.com/news flash',
picture: 'http://mysitehere.com/images/GILAND.jpg',
caption: 'Caption here',
description: 'Description here.',
message: ''
});
});
});
</script>
<img src = "images/share_button.png" id = "share_button">
```

Comment: you should make the app live in the developer.facebook.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to go on the App Review's tab of the Facebook app https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[[your_app_id]]/review-status/, you have to make your app public so other people can use it.